# AWS SWF Sample Code issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am new to Amazon simple workflow service and am following [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/getting-started-example-helloworldworkflow.html?shortFooter=true) to understand SWF.

As per the documentation, once you execute the GreeterMain class after executing the GreeterWorker class, you should see active workflow execution on AWS console. However thats not the case with me. On executing the GreeeterMain class, the application prints out `Hello World` but I do not see any active workflows in "My Worfkflow Executions" sections on AWS console. I am not getting any errors as well.

On executing the GreeterWorker class, I can see "Workflow Types" and "Activities Types" section populated with appropriate workflows and activities.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please help out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh.. Found it.... As per doc, you create class with name "GreeterMain" in two different packages. One package is basic code path, second uses AWS SWF. While executing Eclipse was referring to basic code path and not invoking AWS SWF.